# Using Waiting Dialog with navigation to another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to use Waiting Dialog in my App using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

I have a button in my app. when user click on it, we navigate to another viewController:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
ViewController2 *yourViewController = (ViewController2 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FavoritePage"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
```

And as you know it can also be set from `interface builder`.

The things is it takes a short while until next page loads, and I want to show a Waiting Dialog in this period:

```
- (IBAction)navigation:(id)sender {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *yourViewController = (ViewController2 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FavoritePage"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
}
```

but it does not work.

When I remove the code related to navigation, and just use this:

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
```

Waiting Dialog become appear, but when I use the navigation codes and this line, the waiting Dialog is not displayed and navigation works.

How can I make them work together?

Just want to add that to hide the Waiting Dialog, I have this also :

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of,

```
- (IBAction)navigation:(id)sender {
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *yourViewController = (ViewController2 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FavoritePage"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Try,

```
- (IBAction)navigation:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    ViewController2 *yourViewController = (ViewController2 *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FavoritePage"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view  animated:YES];
}
```

or else, you need to add `showHUDAddedTo` method in `ViewController2`'s `viewWillAppear` method.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but when I click on the button it takes some seconds until we navigate to other page. (because it started to read the data from cloud). So what I see is the first page in the seconds. I want to add the ProgressHUD there. when Second page loads there is no need to show the waiting dialog.

Comment: Is there any way to use a kind of AsyncTask in iPhone? (that could be possible in Android)

Comment: In that case you need to add it on self.navigationController.view instead of yourViewController.view, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for your point. it was useful. I think this is your right answer: self.navigationController.view

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your `- (IBAction)navigation:(id)sender {}`
 because you first, show the `MBProgressHUD` and then pushing to the `ViewController2`. So, the  `MBProgressHUD` has been shown but with that it pushes to new view, too.

If you want to show the waiting sign, then you can use `MBProgressHUD` with timer. Set timer for 1.0 or 2.0 secs. and after that call `navigation` method. Make the timer invalidate and remove the `MBProgressHUD`.

Or else, you can use

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourMethod) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];`

in `- (IBAction)navigation:(id)sender {}.

and call this `NSNotification` from another view like `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:nil];`

`

Comment: Your suggestion for calling timer is not good. I do not plan to make the App more time consuming.

Comment: Your suggestion for using `NSNotification`is good. but the thing is I am using storyboard. I could not make the Notification works in a way that I want. Have you implemented such a thing or it was just a guess? If you have experience please share more code. (just want to add that I know how to use notification, but how can we make it works with ProgressDialog?)

Comment: @Ali I haven't used `NSNotification` in Storyboard.... but as you said about timer, I think it won't be time consuming or load the application. It creates its own thread, and operated separately. And once your are done, invalidate the timer. So, from my point of view, you at least try out the `NSTimer scheduleTimer.....`..:)

Comment: by the way, thanks that you shared your ideas with me. +1 point.